# sql query depending on case statement

Tags: php, sql, switch-statement

Can not get the correct case to run the query... I have the variables listed elsewhere in the page...

> if (isset($_SESSION['user_level']))
>                               {...

and then a block of code for pagination...(which works fine)

and the rest of the code

```
$user_level = ($_SESSION['user_level']);


switch ('user_level'){

    case 0:
        $user_level = "SELECT * FROM cases WHERE  $current_user = user_id  ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start_from, $per_page ";
        break;
    case 1:
        $user_level = "SELECT * FROM cases WHERE $current_user = user_id  ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start_from, $per_page  ";
        break;
    case 2:
        $user_level = "SELECT * FROM cases ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start_from, $per_page  ";
        break;
    case 3:
        $user_level = "SELECT * FROM cases ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start_from, $per_page ";
        break;
    default:
    $user_level = "SELECT * FROM cases ORDER by $order_by LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";

        }
$query = $user_level;
```

and ends with a WHILE statement.
If I just use... $query = "SELECT..." it returns all rows, and every user sees everyone elses rows.
I have adjusted the user_level inside the database to gather a clue but haven't.
The user levels are new_user, normal_user, technichian, admin. and each have different permissions.

Comment: `switch ($user_level){`, no?

Comment: Please check the `switch` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). As chris85 said you must provide an variable and not a static string if you want make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing here:

```
switch ('user_level'){
```

The variable is called `$user_level`. So:

```
switch ($user_level) {
```